# Multiple If else statements on Search Result Page

Tags: post-meta

Ok, I have a few CPT's setup with a metabox that only requires some values for some categories.  When searching a specific category, I want to display a link to the value (which is a url) if it exists and not show it if it doesn't.  What I have right now show's all three buttons whether the value exists or not.  Anyone know how I can display just one read more button depending on whether or not the meta value exists?

```
    <?php if( get_post_meta($post->ID, 'recent_action', true) ) { ?>

            <a class="button" href="<?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID, "recent_action", true); ?>">Recent Action Link</a>

            <?php } ?>

            <?php if( get_post_meta($post->ID, 'related_link', true) ) { ?>

            <a class="button" href="<?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID, "related_link", true); ?>">Related Link</a>

            <?php } ?>

            <?php if( get_post_meta($post->ID, 'imp_docs_link', true) ) { ?>

            <a class="button" href="<?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID, "imp_docs_link", true); ?>">Important Documents Link</a>

            <?php } ?>
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
<?php if(strlen(get_post_meta($post->ID, 'recent_action', true)) !== 0){ ?>
            <a class="button" href="<?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID, "recent_action", true); ?>">Recent Action Link</a>
<?php } elseif(strlen(get_post_meta($post->ID, 'related_link', true)) !== 0){ ?>
            <a class="button" href="<?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID, "related_link", true); ?>">Related Link</a>
<?php } elseif(strlen(get_post_meta($post->ID, 'imp_docs_link', true)) !== 0){ ?>
            <a class="button" href="<?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID, "imp_docs_link", true); ?>">Important Documents Link</a>
<?php } ?>
```

or better yet (situation depends on increased reliability):

```
<?php if(!empty(get_post_meta($post->ID, 'recent_action', true))){ ?>
            <a class="button" href="<?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID, "recent_action", true); ?>">Recent Action Link</a>
<?php } elseif(!empty(get_post_meta($post->ID, 'related_link', true))){ ?>
            <a class="button" href="<?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID, "related_link", true); ?>">Related Link</a>
<?php } elseif(!empty(get_post_meta($post->ID, 'imp_docs_link', true))){ ?>
            <a class="button" href="<?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID, "imp_docs_link", true); ?>">Important Documents Link</a>
<?php } ?>
```

Using strlen() if you are certain the return will be a string. Use empty() for all other situations.

Comment: If `get_post_meta` returns an array: This will throw an `E_WARNING` and the expression will evaluate to `true` since `NULL !== 0` in PHP 5.3+ or an `E_NOTICE` with a `true` expression because `5 !== 0` in PHP 5.2.x and under. And that regardless of whether the array is empty or not.

Comment: Why was my answer downvoted? Because i did not use the empty() function?

Comment: @Ronburgundy: Yes. See above comment.

Comment: The code was written with the assumption the user would fetch the proper data type from the post meta. Had he indicated he was retrieving a array, strlen would not have been used. I see the advantages of empty() but i do not find strlen to be improper in this situation.

Comment: Regardless I have updated my answer.

Comment: Well, for another, `empty` is a language construct, whereas `strlen` is a built-in function. Generally, the earlier will perform *much* faster than the latter. Granted, the initial method being "close to wrong" is purely my opinion and subjective. Don't take it as personal offence, that I downvoted *this answer*. ;)

Comment: Certainly, Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

PHP's [`empty`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php) is meant for this.

```
if(!empty(get_post_meta($post->ID, 'recent_action', true))) {
  // there is data; do stuff
} elseif (!empty(get_post_meta($post->ID, 'related_link', true))) {
  // there is data; do stuff
} // and so on
```